# D3js : Circle packing - Dice Pattern inside Circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I am following the link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535 to pack circles. I have gone through the pack layout and could not find pack.position to customize the position of circles to be packed. Currently I have the following output with my data where 5 circles are randomly positioned inside the circle.

[image: Default position of packed circles]

But I want to customize to the dice pattern like the following

[image: Dice pattern of the circles packed]

Could anyone help me to customize the position of circles. 
I would like to know whether it is possible to customize the position(Override default position method).

Comment: I am confused by your question. The purpose of a circle pack layout is to calculate positions and sizes of circle pack diagram. Now you want not to use such positions, but to use ones that would be basically precalculated, following dice pattern. Why then you need to make use of circle pack layout at all?

Comment: Because if the no of circles are more than 6 then they have to be packed with the position calculated by the layout. I want to customize it only for 3-6 circles and not for all.